# How to resolve constraint errors with autoincremented primary key

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create an INSERT statement into an Access database using ucanaccess.

My  statement is:

```
String stg = "INSERT INTO PatientData (FName,SName,DOB) VALUES('Bilbo','Baggins','1777')";
```

The table has a `H_Id` as its primary key which autoincrements

When I run my statement I get the error:

> integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10583 table: PATIENTDATA column: H_ID

How do I account for the autoincrements in the `INSERT` statement

Comment: by primary investigation i found you are entering wrong data in 3rd field,i mean at DOB.please provide your table structure for accurate answer.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: the DBMS is Access 2013

Comment: Double-check the AutoIncrement property of the primary key. I betcha it's not set.

Comment: Haha. Well done. You were right. Not sure if I should just delete the whole question- but post as an answer to be embarrassment and the tick is yours